# Matrix-vector multiplications using OpenCL

Tags: opencl, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I have 2 different programs.

First makes matrix-matrix multiplication using opencl. On my GPU it produces much better results, then on host CPU (0.2 seconds vs 18 seconds, for example).

Second makes matrix-vector multiplication using opencl, and it works on GPU slightly slower, then on host CPU.

What are the reasons?

Here is kernel

```
__kernel void matrixVectorMul(__global float* resultVector,
    __global float* matrixA,
    __global float* vectorB, 
    int width_A)
{
    int tx = get_global_id(0); 

    float value = 0;
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < width_A; ++k) {
        value += matrixA[tx * width_A + k] * vectorB[k];
    }

    resultVector[tx] = value;
}
```

And host code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include "cl.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>

#define LOCAL_SIZE 512
#define WIDTH_A (4096*2)
#define HEIGHT_A (4096*2)

float *matrix_A;
float *vector_B;
float *result_vector;
float *result_vector_host;

void randomInit(float *data, int size) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
}

void GenerateTestData() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));    

    unsigned int size_A = WIDTH_A * HEIGHT_A;
    matrix_A = new float[size_A];

    vector_B = new float[WIDTH_A];

    randomInit(matrix_A, size_A);
    randomInit(vector_B, WIDTH_A);

    result_vector = new float[WIDTH_A];
    result_vector_host = new float[WIDTH_A];
}

void PerformCalculationOnDevice(cl::Device device) {
    clock_t start_t, end_t;
    start_t = clock();
    std::vector<cl::Device> contextDevices;
    contextDevices.push_back(device);
    cl::Context context(contextDevices);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);

    std::fill_n(result_vector, WIDTH_A, 0);

    cl::Buffer cl_matrix_A = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, WIDTH_A * HEIGHT_A * sizeof(float), matrix_A);
    cl::Buffer cl_vector_B = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, WIDTH_A * sizeof(float), vector_B);
    cl::Buffer cl_result_vector = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY|CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, WIDTH_A * sizeof(float), result_vector);
    end_t = clock();
    std::cout << "Context, queue, buffers " << (float)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    std::ifstream sourceFile("MatrixVectorMultiplicationKernel.cl");
    std::string sourceCode(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()+1));
    cl::Program program = cl::Program(context, source);
    program.build(contextDevices);
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "matrixVectorMul");

    int iArg = 0;
    kernel.setArg(iArg++, cl_result_vector);
    kernel.setArg(iArg++, cl_matrix_A);
    kernel.setArg(iArg++, cl_vector_B);
    kernel.setArg(iArg++, WIDTH_A);

    start_t = clock();
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(HEIGHT_A), cl::NDRange(LOCAL_SIZE));
    queue.finish();

    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(cl_result_vector, CL_TRUE, 0, WIDTH_A * sizeof(float), result_vector);
    end_t = clock();
    std::cout << "enqueueNDRangeKernel and enqueueReadBuffer " << (float)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;
}

void PerformCalculationOnHost() {
    float tmp;
    for(int row_A = 0; row_A < HEIGHT_A; row_A++) {
        tmp = 0;
        for(int col_A = 0; col_A < WIDTH_A; col_A++) {
            tmp += matrix_A[row_A * WIDTH_A + col_A] * vector_B[col_A];
        }
        result_vector_host[row_A] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    GenerateTestData();

    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    clock_t start_t = clock();
    for (unsigned int iPlatform=0; iPlatform<platforms.size(); iPlatform++) {
        platforms[iPlatform].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &devices);
        for (unsigned int iDevice=0; iDevice<devices.size(); iDevice++) {
            try {
                PerformCalculationOnDevice(devices[iDevice]);
            } catch (cl::Error error) {
                std::cout << error.what() << "(" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;   
            }
        }
    }
    clock_t end_t = clock();
    std::cout << "Device: " << (float)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << std::endl;
    start_t = clock();
    PerformCalculationOnHost();
    end_t = clock();
    std::cout << "Host: " << (float)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds" << std::endl;
    int errors = 0;
    float mean_deviation = 0;
    FILE *f, *f_host;
    f = fopen("device_result", "w");
    f_host = fopen("host_result", "w");
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH_A; i++) {
            if(fabs(result_vector[i] - result_vector_host[i]) > 1E-3) {
                errors++;
            }
            fprintf(f, "%.2f\n", result_vector[i]);
            fprintf(f_host, "%.2f\n", result_vector_host[i]);
            mean_deviation += fabs(result_vector[i] - result_vector_host[i]);
    }
    fclose(f); fclose(f_host);
    mean_deviation /= WIDTH_A;
    std::cout << "Errors = " << errors << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Mean deviation = " << mean_deviation << std::endl;

    delete[](matrix_A);
    delete[](vector_B);
    delete[](result_vector);
    delete[](result_vector_host);
    return 0;
}
```

And when i run it, i get following results

```
Context, queue, buffers 0.45
enqueueNDRangeKernel and enqueueReadBuffer 1.31
Device: 1.79 seconds
Host: 1.42 seconds
Errors = 0
Mean deviation = 8.78572e-05
```

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the local size? CPU's and GPU's have very different optimal local work group sizes, for instance my CPU has 1024 but my GPU has 64. I think you could try transposing the matrix to benefit from sequential memory reads, right now they are interleaved.

Comment: This program is mostly for demonstration purposes. I got local size using another simple program, which queries some parameters of GPU.
I've tried to copy vectorB into local array in kernel (i guess, it must give speedup), but it does not compiles. But if i simply declare local array and do not try to access it's elements, it compiles well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To increase GPU efficiency in this case, more work-items are needed (one per output value is not enough) and the compute/memory access ratio should be higher (i.e. reuse values multiple times when possible).

I have written a few pages on this problem some time ago, if you are interested: [GPU matrix-vector product](http://www.bealto.com/gpu-gemv.html).

Comment: One idea to speed this up, would be to compute simultaneously the product of the same matrix with multiple vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using local memory for vectorB? Each element is read by all work items, so it makes sense to read it from local. I hard-coded the local memory size to 8192 below, but you can play around with the number yourself. (8192 floats being the max for opencl 1.1/1.2)

Also, try using a work group size a multiple of 16 (64 or 128 should work well) for GPU if you can.

```
__kernel void matrixVectorMul(__global float* resultVector,
    __global float* matrixA,
    __global float* vectorB, 
    int width_A)
{
    int tx = get_global_id(0);
    __local float vectB[4096*2];

    event_t copy_event = async_work_group_copy(vectB, vectorB, 4096*2, 0);
    wait_group_events(1,copy_event);

    float value = 0;
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < width_A; ++k) {
        value += matrixA[tx * width_A + k] * vectB[k];
    }

    resultVector[tx] = value;
}
```